# how to find out current uiviewcontroller

Tags: uiviewcontroller

In my application, I am having following UIViewControllers;

```
HomeViewController
FirstViewController
SecondViewController, and etc...
```

My question is;
How can I find out whether SecondViewController is a current UIViewController or not ?

Comment: In what context or scope are you needing this?

Comment: In my application, I have used Push Notification. After receiving a push notification, I have to go to a SecondViewController from HomeViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find out the solution. Here is the code;

```
if([[self.navigationController visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
{
}
else{
}
```